# How to install or copy the driver i.e .ko file to a particular location via makefile?

Tags: linux-kernel, makefile, driver

This is my makefile:

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
    obj-m := dmcdus_dd.o
else
    KDIR := /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic/

    all:
        $(MAKE) INSTALL_MOD_DIR=kernel/drivers/input/touchscreen -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD modules_install
endif

clean: 
    rm -rf *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c .tmp_versions sample Module.symvers
```

I have specified my required path where i have to move my dmcdus_dd.ko file using INSTALL_MOD_DIR & install it by modules_install. When i type "make" in the console i get the following results in the console:

```
make INSTALL_MOD_DIR=kernel/drivers/input/touchscreen -C /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-49-generic/ M=$PWD modules_install
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-49-generic'
DEPMOD  3.5.0-49-generic
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-49-generic'
```

But when i go to the location "/lib/modules/3.5.0-49-generic/kernel/drivers/input/touchscreen" i dont see dmcdus.ko file in that directory... How can i copy my driver to that location?

Comment: did you find it in /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-49-generic/extra ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before installing first you need to make module using `make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules`. 
If you want to make little change in your makefile then write in following way:

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
        obj-m := dmcdus_dd.o
else
        KDIR := /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic/

all:
        make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules #I've changed makefile here
        $(MAKE) INSTALL_MOD_DIR=kernel/drivers/input/touchscreen -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD modules_install
endif
clean: 
        rm -rf *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c .tmp_versions sample Module.symvers
```

- And make sure that you  have permission to copy file to destination (/input/**touchscreen**)folder. If not then change it.

Answer (score 1):

The below makefile is sufficient for you to build and install module

```
obj-m := dmcdus_dd.o
KDIR := /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic/

all:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD modules
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD modules_install

clean:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD clean
```

If you specify INSTALL_MOD_DIR then the modules is moved to that directory

> make **INSTALL_MOD_DIR=kernel/drivers/input/touchscreen** -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD modules_install